# {{layout}} handle in email

Tags: magento-enterprise, promotions

I am trying to display cart contents in the stock EE abandon cart email.

The challenge here is that the email doesn't seem to have the same access to the quote as similarly formatted order emails.

Ideally I can do something along the lines of:

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

Though, obviously, with the relevant quote to the email being sent. How would I create a rewrite that would set access to the $quote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, on the surface this looks like there are a lot of ways to do this. These mails are sent in `Enterprise_Reminder_Model_Rule::sendReminderEmails()`, either through an observer or through an adminhtml action. (*If they were only sent through an observer you wouldn't necessarily need a rewrite, as you could reconfigure the observer to point to your own custom class.*) So, really, we are left with rewriting the `enterprise_reminder/rule` class.

Adding dynamic info to Magento's transactional emails occurs one of two ways. The most direct (and frequent) way this occurs is via an array arg passed in the fifth param of `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::sendTransactional()`:

```
public function sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $email, $name, $vars=array(), $storeId=null)
{
    //....
}
```

Variables passed there are referenced in email templates via the `{{var ...}}` syntax. Another way - the way in question - is to execute view logic via blocks via layout XML execution. This is much more suitable when there is extensive view logic which should be defined once and referenced elsewhere.

The big problem with either approach for getting quote context into the rule-based emails is that the quotes are never invoked during rule processing. This makes sense in a way, because every customer only ever has one quote, and we are dealing with a lot of customers here. Whether intentional or not, this is part of the architecture in this corner of the EE code: customer & their quotes are processed against the rule and this processed data is stored into a lookup table (ref. `Enterprise_Reminder_Model_Rule::_matchCustomers()`), which is then used as a small-footprint set for sending. Related quote data is nowhere to be found.

This background points to a couple of runtime solutions, neither of which is tenable. You could use `{{layout}}` to add in a cart block and custom logic, but then for every single email you are loading a quote record based on customer ID. One Quote + quote_item query per email seems like it would fall over. Another approach of which I'd at least be wary is the loading up/joining of quote & quote_item collections at runtime for the purpose of passing quote data in. This is the better of the two, but that's going to be a large query; perhaps a custom resource collection can be created along with your custom quote_items block and this would suffice. You could also index the fields to some flat model, or modify the `enterprise_reminder_rule_coupon` table and add a column with the quote_item fields you need (along with an index process).

Cheers.